# Request HTML5 video fullscreen on Apple's devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, fullscreen

Hello guys I have got custom fullscreen icon that triggers fullscreen on my video. Everything is ok except that it doesn't work on Apple's devices. Do you know how to fix that?

```
$('.fullscreen_btn').click(function() {
    fullscreen=true;
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById('videoAbout');
    if(mediaElement.requestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.requestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(mediaElement.msRequestFullScreen) {
        mediaElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
});
```

As I said - code above is working on Windows/android devices, but not on Apple's.

Comment: It works on Mac - That's a apple devices so what's the problem? Maybe you should say iOS next time...

Comment: Sorry, problem is existing on iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sloved my question. All i had to do is that:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('videoAbout');
mediaElement.webkitEnterFullscreen();
mediaElement.enterFullscreen();
```

This is opening fullscreen on HTML5 video on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from the website

> In Safari, the built-in video controls include a play/pause button, volume control, and a time scrubber. In Safari 5.0 and later on the desktop and on iOS 4.2 on the iPad, the controls also include a full-screen playback toggle on the lower right. The controls automatically fade out when the video is playing and fade in when the user hovers over the video or touches it.

I also says If you embed audio or video in your website, you should use HTML5. you might be using old html4, I don't know. Try this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Yea but i want controls to stay hidden all the time :/ I want to toggle fullscreen with custom button