# In Safari video player shows black screen when playing it full screen only IOS 14 & > version

Tags: jquery, ios14

My player was working just fine before iOS 14. It's working fine on some devices now but in iPhone xs and x player isn't working properly. When playing videos in fullscreen it is just playing audio with a black screen.
In my player when clicking anywhere in the video it goes fullscreen. To make the player full screen I use the webkitEnterFullscreen() method for IOS devices.

```
$("#player_id").on("click", function (e) {
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i))
   $("#player_id video")[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
});
```

Sample screen[image]

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Issue fixed after adding the method enterFullscreen mentioned in the below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184881/14000821