# full screen API alternative for safari, iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a video on my web page, which must open on full screen when user touch it (on mobiles). of course all works great with full screen API on android, but not on iPhones.

I'm aware, that full screen API is not fully supported on iPhones, but is there any alternative for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request HTML5 video fullscreen on Apple's devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182468/request-html5-video-fullscreen-on-apples-devices)